# Возвращение значения функции int C#

Tags: c#, функции

У меня есть функция:

```
static int Example(int a, int b)
{
    if (a>b)
      return 1;
    else if (a<b)
      return 2;
    else if (....)
      return 3;
    ...
}
```

, в которой проверяется что-то с помощью if'ов и потом берется значение из этих if'ов и возвращается.
Но функция типа `int` всегда должна возвращать значение, то есть после прохождения я должен написать еще один `return`, но если я его напишу возвращаться будет значение только из этого return'а. Как мне возвращать значения только из if'ов?

Comment: а проблема то в чём? И подробнее о `но если я его напишу возвращаться будет значение только из этого return'а` что-то вы не то делаете. Весь код приводите тогда...

Comment: понял как исправить
нужно завести переменную с=0;
и после каждой ветки if изменять ее значение
а в конце написать return c;

Comment: @РустемВалеев: А где в вашем коде переменная `c`?

Comment: И подумайте, что должна возвращать ваша функция, если ни одно из условий не выполняется.

Comment: @РустемВалеев Приведите пожалуйста более подробный код и напишите своё решение, иначе ценность этого вопроса стремится к нулю.

Comment: перед всеми if'ами введу переменную int c=0;
если же условия не будут выполняться,вернется 0

Comment: @РустемВалеев приведите полный код, мы подскажем как его лучше записать. Пока это набор костылей какой-то.

Comment: я уже понял в чем ошибка, просто нужно не писать кучу ретёрнов,а завести переменную,которую потом и верну,всем спасибо

Comment: @РустемВалеев есть 2 принципиальгно разных мнения: "точка выхода (return) должна быть одна" и "выходить из функции надо там где она логически завершила работу". Оба варианта со своими тараканами, истина где-то между ними.

Comment: @РустемВалеев можно и одной строкой `return a > b ? 1 : a < b ? 2 : 3;` только читабельность у нее стремится к нулю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static int Example(int a, int b)
    {
        if (a > b)
            return 1;
        if (a < b)
            return 2;
        return 3;
    }
```

Просто компилятор не понимает, что или < или > или ==

Comment: Он мог бы понять, но поскольку подобное соображение помогает в подавляющем меньшинстве случаев, то компилятор этим не занимается.

Comment: Вообще говоря, не обязательно либо `<`, либо `>`, либо `==`. Взять к примеру `double.NaN`. Любое сопоставление с ним вернет `false`. [Пример](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Cj9su2).

Comment: @ Dmitry D. Речь о конкретном коде от ТС (int)

Answer (score 2):

```
switch (a.CompareTo(b))
{
    // a < b
    case -1:
      return 2;
    // a>b
    case 1:
      return 1;
    // a=b (или что то другое)
    default:
      return 3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static int Example(int a, int b)
{
    if (a>b)
      return 1;
    else if (a<b)
      return 2;
    else if (....)
      return 3;
    else // если ни одно из условий не подходит, то вернуть, например, 0
      return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static int Example(int a, int b)
{
    int result = 3;

    if (a>b)
        result = 1;
    if (a<b)
        result = 2;

    return result;
}
```